# How to clone a repository from Heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I have made a Python Application and uploaded it in github.

Then i made a heroku app ad connected to the github repository.'
There is a data.json in my application repository that keeps some info. While application is running the application works fine and data also stores and retrive from there. But when i see in github the file is not changed. Means the data.json file is as it was in the begining. That means the changed file is somewhere in heroku. How can i download that file so that i can retrive my data

Comment: You shouldn't store changes on the dyno file system, it's ephemeral. Use a database, e.g. Heroku offers Postgres: https://www.heroku.com/postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have pushed using the command

```
git push heroku master
```

You can clone what is pushed using:

```
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```

This of course assumes you have heroku-cli installed.

Comment: But [don't make a habit of it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub."